# Why do you save recursive call result in variable?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

i'm trying learn dfs and saw this code below.

```
def recursive_dfs(v, discovered=[]):
discovered.append(v)
for w in graph[v]:
    if not w in discovered:
        discovered = recursive_dfs(w, discovered)
return discovered
```

I dont understand why we have to save recursive call return value like this `discovered = recursive_dfs(w, discovered)`?

Comment: You're right that you don't have to return the list because it is mutable, but arguably it does make it more user-friendly.

Comment: Note that you should not be using `[]` as the default value. That means every "initial" call like `recursive_dfs(some_node)` is carrying over the results from every previous call.

Comment: Having the function return the list lets you write `result = recursive_dfs(starting_point, [])` instead of `result = []; recursive_dfs(starting_point, result)`. Modifying the list in-place saves you from having to create a new list with every recursive call, like `recursive_dfs(w, discovered + [v])`.